# Convert SQL to Laravel Query Builder With JOIN/SUB Queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

```sql
SELECT user_sessions.os, COUNT(*) FROM user_sessions
    JOIN (SELECT MIN(created_at) AS MinCreatedAt, user_id FROM user_sessions 
    GROUP BY user_id) AS us2
    ON (user_sessions.created_at = us2.MinCreatedAt 
        AND user_sessions.user_id = us2.user_id 
    GROUP BY user_sessions.os
```

This is a raw SQL query which I tried to convert in Eloquent but failed. My trial code is...

```php
$q1 = self::select(DB::raw('MIN(created_at) as MinCreatedAt, user_id'))->groupBy('user_id');
$q2 = self::select(DB::raw('user_sessions.os, count(*)'));

$users = self::
select($q2)->joinSub($q1, 'us2', function ($join) {
$join->on('user_sessions.created_at = us2.MinCreatedAt AND user_sessions.user_id = us2.user_id ');
})->get();
```

**Error**

> stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string object given

Comment: you already do query select in `$q2` so you don't need to do select again in `$user`,  that will be the error because `select()` except string but `$q2` is object

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
$joinQuery = "(".DB::table('user_sessions')
    ->selectRaw('MIN(created_at) AS MinCreatedAt, user_id')
    ->groupBy('user_id')->toSql().") as us2" ;


$users = DB::table('user_sessions')
        ->selectRaw("user_sessions.os, COUNT(*)")
        ->join(DB::raw($joinQuery), function ($join) {
            $join->on('user_sessions.created_at', '=', 'us2.MinCreatedAt')->on('user_sessions.user_id', '=', 'us2.user_id');
        })
        ->groupBy('user_sessions.os');
```

### Update

```
$q1 = self::select(DB::raw('MIN(created_at) as MinCreatedAt, user_id'))->groupBy('user_id');
$q2 = self::select(DB::raw('user_sessions.os, count(*)'));

$users = $q2->joinSub($q1, 'us2', function ($join) {
$join->on('user_sessions.created_at = us2.MinCreatedAt AND user_sessions.user_id = us2.user_id ');
})->groupBy('user_sessions.os')->get();
```

Comment: It is not a proper method and it will not work for me.

Comment: @AhtishamShahid just update it, can you check it again